# Show that $\bigcup_{n=1,2,3,...} [0,1-1/n^2]=[0,1)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

*My proof.*  Initially, we will show that $\bigcup_{n=1,2,3,...} [0,1-1/n^2]\subseteq [0,1)$. For every $n=1,2,3,...$ since $0\leq 1-1/n^2 <1$, we have $[0,1-1/n^2]\subseteq [0,1)$.

Now, we will show vice versa. Let $x\in [0,1)$. i.e., $0\leq x<1$. Since $x<1$, $(1-x)$ is positive. So,, by the Archimedian property, there is a $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n(1-x)>1$. Thus, $0\leq x<1-1/n$. i.e., $x\in [0,1-1/n]$. i.e., $x\in   
\bigcup_{n=1,2,3,...} [0,1-1/n]$.

**So, I couldn't show $x\in \bigcup_{n=1,2,3,...} [0,1-1/n^2]$. Can you check my proof, can you give a hint for second statement in the my proof?**

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If $n(1-x)>1$, then also $n^2(1-x)>1$.

Comment: Yes, by the Archimedian prop. Thanks